# ATTiny to drive LEDs

Tags: arduino-uno, led, pwm, attiny

I'm installing some daylight running lights in my car and I have purchased 2 LED bars, each with 8 white LEDs. They use 12V and I need to make some effect when they turn on. Like in some modern cars, when I turn on the key, LEDs should blink(shake like when old fluorescent tubes turns on) and then turn on slowly(brightness from 0-100).

I can do this with Arduino-Uno and I need to put this in a smaller chip. What would be the best suitable ATTiny chip for this project? Because using an ATmega328 is not worth for a small project like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [ATtiny85](http://www.atmel.com/devices/attiny85.aspx) is an 8-pin AVR device with 3 PWM channels available in DIL and SO packages. The Arduino core can be downloaded from [arduino-tiny](https://code.google.com/p/arduino-tiny/). It can be programmed via ISP using either [ArduinoISP](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoISP) or a dedicated programmer.

Comment: I have done a similar project, and can verify it works well. Make sure you have a transistor between the attiny and the LEDs (and a resistor between the attiny and the transistor!), so the high amps & 12 volts aren't drawn through the attiny. If you step down the voltage from 12v to 5v, make sure you check that they have a common ground - measure the voltage between the car battery's ground (negative) and the attiny's ground.